# What are the alternatives to Activity Monitor that will summarize cpu time over time?

Tags: activity-monitor

Activity monitor is not always good if you want to see what is keeping your computer busy for a period of time.

For example if you have `gcc` executed hundred of times it will take a lot of CPU power but the overall CPU time consumed by gcc will not appear. I'm looking for a solution that is able to count and summarize application usage so I can know that how the cpu was used.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a huge fan of Bjango's [iStat menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/), which allows one to conveniently place various monitors (CPU, disk usage, network up & down, battery, memory, temperature sensors...) up in the menu bar.  Each one can be pulled down like a menu for additional details.  It's a $16 app.  You can try before you buy.

Edit:  it looks like they have released another monitoring application called [MiStat](http://bjango.com/mac/mistat/) that is a separate app instead of living in the menu bar.  This allows them to place it in the Mac App Store.  It's available for a $4.99.

---

**Edit:** I'm sorry, I must have not read your question carefully enough before I posted.  I do not know of any GUI tool that is able to aggregate CPU time being consumed by several similar processes as you describe.   The best idea that I can think of would be to write a script that wraps the top or ps commands and adds up processes that match a regular expression.   This strikes me as a market opportunity for a nice utility.   Could you describe a little more of how you would like such a thing to behave?

Answer (score 0):

For a long time, I used [Ipulse from IconFactory](http://iconfactory.com/software/ipulse/) until my company's IT department clamped down on software installs. It offers up a lot of information about the Mac in a small space. It is a visual tool first that then allows for in-depth, text-based analysis by hovering your mouse over it. It's a bit dated (it still shows Mac OS 10.4 as the minimum requirement), so I suggest you demo it to make sure it still works on your Macs.

Comment: Sorry but ipulse does not summarize cpu usage over time, in fact it looks to be only a fancy vizualization over what `top`vprovides.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use Apple's Instruments' Activity Monitor to record what you want. It's not an always-on solution, but would let you diagnose particular intervals.